# Probability of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-analysis

Assume we have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ where $\mathcal{F} =(\mathcal{F}_t)_{0 \leq t \leq \tau}$ is a Filtration, with $\tau < \infty$. The following definition is from an article im reading and trying to understand. On that probability space we define a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process $D$.

Let $W(t)_{0 \leq t \leq \tau}$ be a brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ which creates the filtration $\mathcal{F} =(\mathcal{F}_t)_{0 \leq t \leq \tau}$. Through the constants $D_0, \theta,\sigma \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and the function $\mu(t)$ we define the OU-process $D(t)$ as solution of the SDE:
\begin{align*}
& d D(t)  = \theta (\mu(t) - D(t)) d t + \sigma d W(t),  & D(0) = D_0 > 0, \quad t > 0. 
\end{align*}

The function $\mu(t)$ is defined as:
\begin{align*}
\mu(t):= a + b \cos(2 \pi t - c)- \frac{2\pi}{\theta} sin(2\pi t - c).
\end{align*}

What I'm curious about is the probability of the OU-Process. The article makes the following argumentation:
Define $\overline{\mu(t)} := a + b \cos(2\pi t -c)$. Then the probabilty follows:
\begin{align*}
P( D(s) \leq x_1 \mid F_t ) = \Phi \left( \frac{x_1- \overline{\mu(s)}-(D(t)-\overline{\mu(t)}) e^{-\theta(s-t)}}{ \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{2 \theta} (1- e^{-2 \theta(s-t)}))}} \Bigg\vert F_t \right)
\end{align*} 
where $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative distrubtion funtion of an $N(0,1)$ random variable.
I found out that a for a general OU-process $X$ we have:
\begin{align*}
X(t) \sim N\left( D(0) \cdot e^{-\overline{\theta}t} +  \overline{\mu}(t) (1-e^{-\overline{\theta}t}), \frac{\overline{\sigma}^2}{2\overline{\theta}} (1- e^{-2\overline{\theta}t}) \right).
\end{align*}

I dont understand the defintion of $\overline{\mu}$, how does that get into $\Phi(\cdot)$.

Why do they use $s-t$ instead of just $s$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $s>t$, you can express $D(s)$ in terms of $D(t)$ and a term that is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$. Then you are able to compute the conditional probability. Specifically,
\begin{align*}
e^{\theta s} D(s) = e^{\theta t} D(t) + \int_t^s \theta e^{\theta v}\mu(v) dv +\sigma\int_t^se^{\theta v}dW_v.
\end{align*}
Here, 
\begin{align*}
\mu(t) = a+ b\big[\cos(2\pi t-c) - \frac{2\pi}{\theta} \sin(2\pi t -c) \big].
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
e^{\theta s} D(s) &= e^{\theta t} D(t) + a\left(e^{\theta s} - e^{\theta t}\right)+b\left[e^{\theta s} \cos(2\pi s-c) - e^{\theta t} \cos(2\pi t-c)\right] + \sigma\int_t^se^{\theta v}dW_v\\
&=e^{\theta t} D(t) + e^{\theta s}\overline{\mu(s)} - e^{\theta t}\overline{\mu(t)} + \sigma\int_t^se^{\theta v}dW_v,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\overline{\mu(t)} = a + b\cos(2\pi t-c).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
D(s) = e^{-\theta(s-t)} D(t)+ \overline{\mu(s)}-e^{-\theta(s-t)}\overline{\mu(t)} + \sigma\int_t^se^{-\theta (s-v)}dW_v.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) &= e^{-\theta(s-t)} D(t)+ \overline{\mu(s)}-e^{-\theta(s-t)}\overline{\mu(t)},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) &=\sigma^2\int_t^se^{-2\theta (s-v)} dv\\
&=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}\left(1-e^{-2\theta (s-t)}\right).
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
P\left(D(s) \le x_1 \mid \mathcal{F}_t \right) &= P\left(\frac{D(s)-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}} \le \frac{x_1-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}} \mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{x_1-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}}\right),
\end{align*}
since
\begin{align*}
\frac{D(s)-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}} = \frac{\sigma\int_t^se^{-\theta (s-v)}dW_v}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}}
\end{align*}
is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$, and 
\begin{align*}
\frac{x_1-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}}
\end{align*}
is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable.

Comment: Hey @Gordon,
how is that? Can you give me another hint?


Do you unterstand how they use $\overline{\mu}$ instead of $\mu$ (see $\mu$ in $X$)?

Comment: @frakChris By the definition of the SDE $dX(t)=b(X(t),t) dt + \sigma(X(t),t) dW(t)$, you have $X(s)=X(t)+\int_t^s b(X(u),u) du + \int_t^s \sigma(X(u),u) dW(u)$. Under appropriate assumptions about $b,\sigma$, these two integrals are independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$. This is ultimately just the Markov property (maybe a slightly stronger version of it).

Comment: Does that give me somthing like: $P( D(s) \leq x_1 \mid F_t ) = P( D(s-t) \leq x_1)$? This is my interpretation of the Markov property

Comment: @frakChris: I provided a full answer.

Comment: @Gordon thanks man. Really appreciated. I check back with it tomorrow and see if I unterstand everything.

Comment: @Gordon. Hey this makes sense to me. But I dont unterstand what you want to say with: 
"since
\begin{align*}
\frac{D(s)-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}} = \frac{\sigma\int_t^se^{-\theta (s-v)}dW_v}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}}
\end{align*}
is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$." $->$ Do you want to say that since this the term on the left hand side is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$ we can use the central limit theorem? But what do you want to explain with the term on the right hand side? Thanks Mate!

Comment: @frakChris: Since the right side is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable and the left side is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$, you can compute the conditional expectation specifically. No central limit theorem is needed here.

Comment: Hey @Gordon, i just checked back to the solution again. 
I unterstand your calculations to the point where we have that:
\begin{align*}
D(s) = e^{-\theta(s-t)} D(t)+ \overline{\mu(s)}-e^{-\theta(s-t)}\overline{\mu(t)} + \sigma\int_t^se^{-\theta (s-v)}dW_v.
\end{align*}.

But why is it so trivial that the last term is the variance and the others are the expectiation. Furthermore I'm not sure why you are able to condition variance and expectation with $\mathcal{F}_t$.

I would be really happy if you could help me again! Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Furthermore @Gordon. I dont say why it is so easy to say that \begin{align*}
\frac{x_1-E\left(D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}{\sqrt{\textrm{Var}\left( D(s) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)}}
\end{align*}
is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable. Can you give a short explaination for that please? 

my best regards
Chris

Comment: @frakChris: The expectation is based on that the expectation of the last term is zero, and the variance is based on Ito's isometry. Regarding the $\mathcal{F}_t$ measureability, it is based on that the conditional expectation is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra where the  conditional expectation is taken on.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you sir. I forgot about the Itô-isometry!